# Pyside6 type error (QScrollArea and QWidget)

Tags: python, pyside6

I have this code:

```python
self.workspace = QtWidgets.QWidget()
self.workspace.setGeometry(70, 0, 1000, 700)
self.workspace.setParent(self.main_widget)
self.workspace.setObjectName('workspace')
self.buttons['orders'].clicked.connect(self.orders_widget)

self.scroll = QtWidgets.QScrollArea
self.scroll.setWidget(self.workspace)
```

And here is strange error:

```bash
TypeError: descriptor 'setWidget' for 'PySide6.QtWidgets.QScrollArea' objects doesn't apply to a 'PySide6.QtWidgets.QWidget' object
```

In the Pyside documentation this function described:

```python
PySide6.QtWidgets.QScrollArea.setWidget(PySide6.QtWidgets.QWidget)
```

I completely confused, help me please

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Typo: `self.scroll = QtWidgets.QScrollArea()`